# How to append in String Builder in java?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have sentence in String X. How can I split each word in sentence and add  a span tag for each word with class `word` and if the word matches with String y add class `word selected`?

Both X and y Are dynamic

```
String X = "The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."
String Y = "community, here"
```

I create a function and split into array , but i am not able  to append to string builder

```
    private String setPType(String X , String Y){
       String[] elements = Y.split(",");
       String[] newElement = X.split(",");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<p id=\"view\">");
        sb.append("</p>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

My output should look like this

```
<p id="view"> 
<span class="word">The</span>
<span class="word selected">community</span> 
<span class="word">is</span> 
<span class="word selected">here</span> 
<span class="word">to</span>
<span class="word ">help</span>
</p>
```

Comment: "but i am not able to append to string builder" I clearly see your code appending strings to a StringBuilder. What's your **actual** issue? Does it not give the output you want? Does it throw an error?

Comment: What i think is you are able to append but you want expected output?

Comment: At what point are you feeding element and newElements into your StringBuilder?

Comment: Well you'd get your desired output only if you put in the effort of looping through the X splits and matching them against a set of Y splits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd split `x` by space, stream it, wrap every word with its span, and then join it back. For the distinction between selected and non selected words, I'd split `y`, store the words in a `Set` (not strictly required, but should improve performance, especially on large inputs), and use that to check for the required class:

```
private static String setPType(String x , String y) {
    Set<String> classifier = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(y.split(", ")));

    return Arrays.stream(x.split(" "))
            .map(w -> {
                String cls = classifier.contains(w) ? "word selected" : "word";
                return String.format("<span class=\"%s\">%s</span>", cls, w);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "<p id=\"view\">\n", "\n</p>"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What looks wrong here, is that you aren't appending the expected values, instead your final string is: `<p id="view"></p>`. Try to add it, some like:

```
sb.append("<p id=\"view\">");
    sb.append("abc");
    sb.append("</p>");
```

Comment: This: doesn't add the newlines, doesn't take into account the strings `X` and `Y`, and essentially omits all the code that **would** actually solve OP's question.

Comment: Exactly @Aplet123... Try to put this as well, but got unvoted LOL